# Solving an unsolvable integral ??

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I recently stumbled upon an indefinite integral . sin(x)/x [ Another similar one is root (x) times sin x.
However if we substitute sin(x) in terms of x as Maclaurin series we could get a series of infinite yet integrable polynomials . What's the catch?

Comment: Then you're left with a sum of infinite terms that has no compact closed form. So you [define one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

Comment: It's not solvable in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Okay I get that fact .

Comment: Ok I get it ....but the thing is it's mentioned as "unintegrable" .

Comment: And what about the root(x) sin(x) one?

Comment: Who mentions that and what **exactly** do they say?

Comment: $$\int \sqrt{x}\sin(x)\; dx = - \sqrt{x} \cos(x) + \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \text{FresnelC}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi}}\right)$$  Again, this can't be expressed in elementary functions.

Comment: @Robert Israel It's mentioned in Class 12 NCERT Mathematics Books Chapter 7 Integrals page 324 bottom.

Comment: The thing is I guess it can be expressed in elementary polynomial functions...just an infinite series

Comment: A series doesn't count as an "elementary function".

Comment: God how could I miss that .

Comment: Robert can you please give your view on NCERT book the page I mentioned as well? Maybe they referred unintegrable in a different sense ?

Comment: Page 38 of this PDF : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lemh201.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwizlujtkubfAhUIWX0KHZ8oA_wQFjAEegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0x8ON34xX-Tuvq9r7RS3KM

Comment: Possible duplicate: [3065762](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065762/why-is-there-no-antiderivative-to-the-integral-of-sinx-x)/[155](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote you're referring to is "It is worth mentioning that integration by parts is not applicable to product of functions in all cases. For instance, the method does not work for $\int \sqrt{x} \sin\; x \; dx$.
The  reason  is  that  there  does  not  exist  any  function  whose  derivative  is
$\sqrt{x} \sin \; x$."

As stated, this is simply wrong.  A correct statement would be that there is not an **elementary** function whose derivative is $\sqrt{x} \sin\; x$.  Integration by parts "works" on $\sqrt{x} \sin\; x$, but it doesn't give you a closed form for the antiderivative.  It will say, e.g., that

$$ \int \sqrt{x} \sin \; x \; dx = \frac{2}{3} x^{3/2} \sin\; x - \frac{2}{3} \int x^{3/2} \cos\; x\; dx $$

which is correct, but not really helpful: it leaves you no closer to finding a formula than before.